# How to create a face mesh based on points from Kinect SDK

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect, kinect-sdk

I want to a generate face in Unity engine, using a Kinekt device. Currently, in my program, I am using HighDefinitionFaceFrameSource from Kinect development kit and with it’s point data I am rendering them using Unitys Gizmos.DrawSphere.

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        _sensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

        if (_sensor != null)
        {
            _bodySource = _sensor.BodyFrameSource;
            _bodyReader = _bodySource.OpenReader();
            _bodyReader.FrameArrived += BodyReader_FrameArrived;

            _faceSource = HighDefinitionFaceFrameSource.Create(_sensor);

            _faceReader = _faceSource.OpenReader();
            _faceReader.FrameArrived += FaceReader_FrameArrived;

            _faceModel = FaceModel.Create();
            _faceAlignment = FaceAlignment.Create();

            _sensor.Open();
        }
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        if (_faceModel == null) return;

        IList<CameraSpacePoint> vertices = _faceModel.CalculateVerticesForAlignment(_faceAlignment);

        _points = vertices.Select(point => new Vector3(point.X, point.Y, point.Z)).ToList();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_faceModel == null) return;

        _points = _faceModel.CalculateVerticesForAlignment(_faceAlignment).Select(point => new Vector3(point.X, point.Y, point.Z)).ToList();
    }

    private void BodyReader_FrameArrived(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null)
            {
                Body[] bodies = new Body[frame.BodyCount];
                frame.GetAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

                Body body = bodies.Where(b => b.IsTracked).FirstOrDefault();

                if (!_faceSource.IsTrackingIdValid)
                {
                    if (body != null)
                    {
                        _faceSource.TrackingId = body.TrackingId;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void FaceReader_FrameArrived(object sender, HighDefinitionFaceFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var frame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (frame != null && frame.IsFaceTracked)
            {
                frame.GetAndRefreshFaceAlignmentResult(_faceAlignment);
                Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUCsG.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y677U.jpg

I’m looking for a way to create a face mesh based on those points. I tried to implement Delaunay triangulation but it didn’t bring good results. What is a proper way of approaching this problem and are there any good examples online?